# Question about MeshFunctions

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need my code to produce a graph of some function (just normal Plot, not Plot3D) with a mesh of 20 based on the x-values and alternating colors between green and yellow.

I have produced the following code:

```
    Plot[x^3, {x, -20, 20}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    MeshStyle -> {Green, Yellow}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> 20]
```

Can someone explain what the {#1&} means and how to make the colors alternate, because currently it is only making a yellow mesh.

Comment: Try `MeshShading -> {Green, Yellow}` see the docs on [MeshFunctions >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeshFunctions.html) on how `MeshFunctions` work.

Comment: you can use both `... MeshStyle -> Red, MeshShading -> {Green, Yellow} ...`; the two options do different things. Regarding the default mesh functions there is a table in [MeshFunctions>> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeshFunctions.html) showing the default settings for various `*Plot*` functions. For `Plot`, the default mesh function uses the `x` values (`#1&` is the first argument)

Comment: What does the #1& refer to?

Comment: Do you want ``Plot[x^3, {x, -20, 20}, PlotLabel -> "Title", PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Green, PointSize[Medium]], 
   Directive[Yellow, PointSize[Medium]]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #1 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Range[-20, 20, 2], Range[-20, 20 , 4]}]``

Comment: for `#`&` see [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15013/dashed-line-with-alternating-colored-dashes

Comment: For `#1` and `&`, you can select each and execute the menu command Help > Find Selected Function. The second hits explain them, as well as the tutorial "Pure Functions" (third hit for `#1`).

Comment: I mind this behavior,your post also include others' efforts.

Comment: @Quantitative - change your mind all you like, but please **stop** deleting the question.

Comment: @Quantitative - basically because you've asked a question that has upvoted answers you aren't allowed to delete it [see this for an explanation of the policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25088/311642)

Comment: @Quantitative - now we come to the real question, why do you **need** the post deleted?  Have you pasted code here that you aren't allowed to paste (as in, you aren't the original author)?

Comment: @Quantitative - would it still be against policy if you rewrote the question, or is the very act of asking a question on here against policy (as in, this is your homework)?

Comment: @Quantitative -- do not sabotage this site.

Answer (score 5):

Since this work,I post it as an answer for reading

```
Plot[x^3, {x, -20, 20}, PlotLabel -> "Title", PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]], 
   Directive[Yellow, PointSize[Medium]]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #1 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Range[-20, 20, 2], Range[-20, 20, 4]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ydoe:  Why include the irrelevant Title?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That inherit from OP :-)

Comment: Change the value in `Range[...,...,...]` or check the documentation of function [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `#1&` means that the mesh is determined by equal steps (say) along the $x$ value on the plot.  Use instead `#2&` if you want it to be along the second or $y$ value on the plot.  In a `Plot3D`, you can use #1& or #2& or #3& ($z$) or combinations thereof.

Try:

```
Plot[.01 x^3, {x, -20, 20},
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Green, PointSize[Medium]], 
   Directive[Yellow, PointSize[Medium]]},
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #2 &},
 Mesh -> {Range[-20, 20, 2], Range[-20, 20, 4]}]
```